E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main error in android studio Android 14
when i run application in android 14 it trough this error:
E/AndroidRuntime(18880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18880): Process: com.technolyte.wencell, PID: 18880
E/AndroidRuntime(18880): java.lang.SecurityException: com.technolyte.wencell: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6193)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1803)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1791)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:766)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at z6.b$b.a(Unknown Source:44)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at z6.b$b.onSuccess(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(Unknown Source:25)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:222)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:314)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8706)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:14678)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$registerReceiverWithFeature$(IActivityManager.java:12184)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:3179)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2884)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880):    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1346)
E/AndroidRuntime(18880): 


in native android you should use context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED) when running on android 14. for flutter please check 3rd party is using this code and possibly update it if there is update
